# How to 3D rotate figures in display

Tags: floats, 3d

I have a bunch of 2D figures which I like to use latex to display them in a row (side by side). Since the number of the figures is a lot I cannot show them all horizontally. For this I would like to have the option to rotate each slightly so that I can show all of them in the limited space. (like the option we have in Microsoft words)

Comment: What do you think about using the option `width=xxcm` for the command `\includegraphics` so that you can put some commands together. You can also use `subfloat`.

Comment: Could you post a link to an example ppicture (someone with more reputation can that include this in your question.)

Comment: I may be interpreting it incorrectly but what you are looking for in similar to [this image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689586/plotting-multiple-images-in-3d-space), right?

Comment: Switching to `landscape` is not an opportunity?

Comment: what is the name of the feature in MS Word that you are referring to? (I am curious).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

works only with `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-3d,graphicx,multido}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\pspicture(12,5)
\multirput[lb](0.25,0)(2.5,0){5}{%     
  \psAffinTransform{0.7 0.3 0 1 0 0}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{xyz}}} 
\endpspicture

\end{document}
```

[image]

`0.7 0.3 0 1 0 0` are the six values for the transformation matrix. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix

Answer (score 17):

Do you mean something like this? The z-axis is slanted 10°, you can compute bigger values if you like.

### Code

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(1cm,0cm)},y={(0cm,1cm)},z={(0.985cm,0.174cm)}]
    \foreach \x in {1,...,5}
    \node[canvas is zy plane at x=3*\x,draw,fill=white] at (0,0) {\includegraphics{book}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

---

**Edit 1:** Now with different pictures of different sizes which are automatically spaced correctly, and easily changable orientation and length of the z-axis:

### Code

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\zangle}{20}
\newcommand{\zlength}{0.707}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\zx}{\zlength*cos(\zangle)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\zy}{\zlength*sin(\zangle)}

\xdef\nextx{0}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(1cm,0cm)},y={(0cm,1cm)},z={(\zx cm,\zy cm)}]
    \foreach \f [count=\x] in {book,book2,book03,bookfour,book5}
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\scalef}{1-\x/10}
        \node[canvas is zy plane at x=\nextx,draw,fill=white,above right] (temp) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=\scalef]{\f}};
        \path (temp.east);
        \pgfgetlastxy{\tempx}{\tempy}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\newx}{(\tempx+3)/28.453}
        \xdef\nextx{\newx}
    }   
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to make lines convergent to simulate perspective?

Comment: @alfC: With _TikZ_ I don't think so.

Comment: This is a great solution.

Answer (score 6):

Introducing `\multirput` instead of `\multido` that has been used in Herbert's answer.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-3d,graphicx,multido}

\begin{document}

\multido{\n=1+1}{5}
{
\begin{pspicture}(4,3)
  \multirput[bl](0,0)(0.62,0){\n}{\psAffinTransform{0.7 0.3 0 1 0 0}{\includegraphics[scale=0.246]{parishilton}}}
\end{pspicture}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Colector Nice, but most printed documents, and indeed most other documents, don't need animated effects.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: This is just an answer for pleasure. :-)

Answer (score 4):

In principle, the images are in 2D, thus rotation could be done only in 2D (x-y axis). But you obtain the effect of a Z rotation with the `width` and `height` options of `\includegraphics`. Therefore you can combine with these options:

**Rotating with enviroments:**

In the preamble `\usepackage{rotating}` allow three environments:

1. `\begin{sideways} ... \end{sideways}` rotate  90 degrees counterclockwise.
2. `\begin{turn}{30} ... \end{turn}` turn 30 degrees. Any positive or negative angle is allowed.
3. `\begin{rotate}{30} ... \end{rotate}` is like turn, but the former add some space to avoid overlapping with text.

**Rotating without environments**:

In the preamble `\usepackage{graphicx}` allow insert images, but also rotation, an you can, for example:

`\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=3cm,angle=90]{example-image}`

Example to see the effect:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[height=3em]{example-image}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=3em,height=3em,angle=15]{example-image}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=2.5em,height=3em,angle=30]{example-image}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=2em,height=3em,angle=45]{example-image}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=1.8em,height=2.8em,angle=60]{example-image}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=1.4em,height=2.6em,angle=90]{example-image}
\end{document}
```

Note that the order of the option `angle` matter, so the above is not the same that:

`\includegraphics[angle=90,width=2cm,height=3cm]{example-image}`

And also you can consider the origin of the rotation:

`\includegraphics[angle=30,origin=rt,width=2cm,height=3cm]{example-image}`

There are also more complicated solutions with packages `tikz` and  `pst-3d` (in this case for .eps images only) that are described in [How to rotate a picture in 3 dimensions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47672/how-to-rotate-a-picture-in-3-dimensions)

Comment: maybe if there were a generalization of the rotate/turn package, maybe a 3D rotation (perspective) can be mocked up.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late, but here's another way to do it with TikZ:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {1,...,5} {
    \begin{scope}[cm={1,0.3,0,1,(\x,0)}]
      \node[transform shape, draw, red, ultra thick, inner sep=0.2mm] {
        \includegraphics[width=2cm]{fz.jpg}
      };
    \end{scope}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]