# Is rotation of symbols around the y axis possible?

Tags: fonts

Is there a way to rotate a symbol any positive degrees around the y axis? The y axis is here taken as the one perpendicular to the text line and lying in the text surface.  E.g., an I would loose its bars with such a rotation of 90 degrees and would be indistinguishable from an O with the same rotation.

Comment: In general No, I would guess but there are some ideas in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73595/how-to-3d-rotate-figures-in-display/73596#73596

Answer (score 8):

Here is a TikZ solution:

```
\tikz\node[xscale={cos(\angle)},inner sep=0]{Texte};
```

Examples:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
Texte%
\foreach \ang in {0,1,...,8,9}{%
  \tikz\node[xscale={cos(\ang*20)},inner sep=0]{RI\ang};%
}...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just `\tikz\node[xscale={cos(\ang*9.9)},inner sep=0]{TI\ang};` should be sufficient.

Comment: @percusse Exact! Thanks. I left lines of code related to other tests...

Comment: Ah yes, one can use that quantity in multiple places.